# Mobile camera as a webcam for Pi 2 via USB

Tags: pi-2, android, python-2.x

How can I use a mobile camera as a webcam for my Pi 2 text recognition idea by connecting the camera to the Pi using USB?

Comment: Have you seen such a setup before, that you think this is possible? If yes, where have you seen it? AFAIK there is no smartphone that allows access to its camera via USB. Not even by running a custom app. But there are accessory cameras for smartphones that are connected via USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with a project about text recognition, I'd encourage you to not put more obstacles in your way than necessary. Sticking to well know and approved ways that have been paved for you will enable you to progress faster. After you've reached a point where your setup is working with the established camera module ([which you can get quite cheap](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Raspberry-Pi-Camera-Module-China-Version-FZ0364-Free-Shipping-Dropshipping/1752058692.html?spm=a2g0s.13010208.99999999.274.34213c00jJ7pLt)), you can try tinkering to use an mobile phones camera.